# Custom Editor of Grid does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using grids popup editor to edit the grid row. in that I am using custom editor (DropDown control) for some of field of Grid. Following is code for that Dropdown editor:

```
function prontoStratumDropDownEditor(container, options) {
          $('<input required data-text-field="ABC" data-value-field="XYZ" name="' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                 dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "SomeURL",
                            type: "get",
                            datatype: "json",
                        }
                    }
                 }),
                 filter: "startswith",
                 suggest: true,
                 }
            });
    }
```

When I click on Edit Command of Grid, ideally dropdown should show me the name of already existing field For Eg: if grid row contain value "Animal" then when I click on Edit, by default DropDown should have "Animal" selected, but its not. I tried many things like getting rid of name property, remove required attribute etc but I do not know Why it is not showing me can anyone please help?

Comment: Ask for more things if needed...

Comment: Suppose options has a field "originalValue". You could try adding a dataBound event handler to the drop down list, that will do a this.text(options.originalValue).  That should make the value be preselected when the drop down is opened.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your code?